# TextView does not stick to the right, instead ovelaps

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a custom listView item with an image button and two textviews. The textview should be on the right as I am getting on the image below(android studio)

[image]

but I am getting this instead

[image]

The xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/account_item"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:longClickable="true"
android:clickable="true">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/account_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:text="1234567890"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="30-15-10"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/account_number"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/account_number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The parent layout is this:

```
       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/accounts_list"
            android:layout_below="@id/accounts_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

Halp?

Comment: Are they wrapped in a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Hi. Yes they are, I dont know why I didn't paste it

Comment: If you have the parent set to wrap content then the alignParentEnd will not be at the far end of the item.

Comment: Hmm, mb a parent of the relative layout is smaller than the width of the screen (or the visible area on your screenshot)?

Comment: @Android777 added the parent layout too. So you think they're overflowing?

Comment: Looks ok to me. Anyway, to enforce non-overlapping you can try to add this line to the first textview: `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"`. However, in this case it'll be harder to achieve the effect when left sides of the two lines of text are aligned (perhaps; needs testing).

Comment: @Android777 Thanks, I will try another layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

> android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

instead of

> android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm